# Store batch unique ID in kafka-streams local store (rocksdb)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm working on a common case for kafka transactional processing:

1. Read batch from `Topic A`
2. Process batch (business logic)
3. Save to database (commit DB transaction for whole batch)
4. Send batch to `Topic B` (commit Kafka transaction)

Currently, i'm using same database for business data and for saving `Batch ID (partition + offset)` for the sake of a case, when step `3` passes successfully, but step `4` fails due to whole application crash. Such that on recoverable application startup i can verify, that current batch, which was received again (due to the lack of commit on step `4` before the crash) was already  processed and i can jump straight to the step `4`.

I'm considering to use Kafka Streams to solve next issues:

1. Offload the main business database and store `Batch ID` in kafka streams local state store (rocksdb), since the verification request (which guarantees service's idempotence) executes on every batch
2. Leverage the local store LRU if the batch is really fat.

Does Kafka-Streams is a right choice for this purpose ?

**P.s.** i'm asking here, since i didn't find any source (searched in kafka docs, conferences, talks) for information about local store mechanics and how does it works under the hood.

Comment: under the hood mechanics can be found at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Internal+Data+Management

Comment: yep, thanks, but it's quite brief and doesn't cover necessary aspects for enterprise grade solution